# What are some good approaches that I can use to count the number of people in a crowd?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, reference-request, algorithm-request

What are some good approaches that I can use to count the number of people in a crowd?

Tracking each person individually is obviously not an option. Any good approaches or some references to research papers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here a convolutional neural network (cNN) based approach is presented:
[Image Crowd Counting Using Convolutional Neural Network and Markov Random Field](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03686)

This blog post has more of a tutorial character and also present an approach based on CNNs
[Counting Crowds and Lines](https://blog.dimroc.com/2017/11/19/counting-crowds-and-lines/)